# Do I need to run "make clean" before ./configure when reconfiguring?

Tags: autotools

Suppose I've ran `./configure` and `make`, but now I want to change a parameter in the configure script. Do I need to run `make clean` before `./configure`, or will everything be OK even if I don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases things might be OK if you don't run `make clean`, but you can't assume they will.

An example of how things might go wrong: a configure flag might add a `-D` parameter to a `CFLAGS` variable or `DEFS`, instead of defining it through `config.h`. The latter would give your C files a dependency on `config.h` which in turn gets regenerated when you re-run `configure`. But in the former case, if you run `configure` again and change that flag, the set of `#defined` symbols in your C files will be different, but those C files will not be recompiled.

Answer (score 3):

`configure` scripts are designed to run 'out-of-tree'. e.g., you can make a subdirectory `build` and run `../configure [options]` from there, which will (ideally) only affect the `build` directory.

If you're using `./configure`, you should run `make clean` prior to running `configure` again - just to be safe. Otherwise, if you're worried about side-effects, a properly written autotools suite should allow for an out-of-tree build directory.

Comment: How would the out-of-tree build directory help if I don't delete it and just re-run `./configure`? What would be different? Otherwise it's an extra step, just the same as running `make clean`.

Comment: @sashoalm - running `make clean` or `make distclean` is somehow a time-consuming bottleneck in you development pipeline? The autotools are complex enough without trying to take 'clever' shortcuts, that might be anything but.